# Opendkim fails to start on CentOS 7 (connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused)

Tags: postfix, centos7, opendkim, milter

I've got issues with OpenDKIM not starting on my CentOS 7 (with Postfix) server since an update for OpenDKIM crashed a while ago.

I've tried the following:

```
service opendkim start
```

Then it says:

```
Job for opendkim.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status opendkim.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then:

```
systemctl status opendkim.service
```

It says:

```
    ● opendkim.service - DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-29 16:44:13 CET; 3min 40s ago
         Docs: man:opendkim(8)
               man:opendkim.conf(5)
               man:opendkim-genkey(8)
               man:opendkim-genzone(8)
               man:opendkim-testadsp(8)
               man:opendkim-testkey
               http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html
      Process: 14228 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=127)

    systemd[1]: Starting DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter...
    systemd[1]: opendkim.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
    systemd[1]: Failed to start DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
    systemd[1]: Unit opendkim.service entered failed state.
    systemd[1]: opendkim.service failed.
```

Then I've tried:

```
journalctl -xe
```

This and (/var/log/maillog) give the related error:

```
postfix/smtpd[32230]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused
```

Config OpenDKIM (/etc/opendkim.conf):

```
##  Create a socket through which your MTA can communicate.
## Socket       inet:8891@localhost
Socket inet:8891@127.0.0.1
```

The entire OpenDKIM config file (/etc/opendkim.conf):

```
## BASIC OPENDKIM CONFIGURATION FILE
## See opendkim.conf(5) or /usr/share/doc/opendkim/opendkim.conf.sample for more

## BEFORE running OpenDKIM you must:

## - make your MTA (Postfix, Sendmail, etc.) aware of OpenDKIM
## - generate keys for your domain (if signing)
## - edit your DNS records to publish your public keys (if signing)

## See /usr/share/doc/opendkim/INSTALL for detailed instructions.

## DEPRECATED CONFIGURATION OPTIONS
##
## The following configuration options are no longer valid.  They should be
## removed from your existing configuration file to prevent potential issues.
## Failure to do so may result in opendkim being unable to start.
##
## Removed in 2.10.0:
##   AddAllSignatureResults
##   ADSPAction
##   ADSPNoSuchDomain
##   BogusPolicy
##   DisableADSP
##   LDAPSoftStart
##   LocalADSP
##   NoDiscardableMailTo
##   On-PolicyError
##   SendADSPReports
##   UnprotectedPolicy

## CONFIGURATION OPTIONS

##  Specifies the path to the process ID file.
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

##  Selects operating modes. Valid modes are s (sign) and v (verify). Default is v.
##  Must be changed to s (sign only) or sv (sign and verify) in order to sign outgoing
##  messages.
Mode    sv

##  Log activity to the system log.
Syslog  yes

##  Log additional entries indicating successful signing or verification of messages.
SyslogSuccess   yes

##  If logging is enabled, include detailed logging about why or why not a message was
##  signed or verified. This causes an increase in the amount of log data generated
##  for each message, so set this to No (or comment it out) if it gets too noisy.
LogWhy  yes

##  Attempt to become the specified user before starting operations.
UserID  opendkim:opendkim

##  Create a socket through which your MTA can communicate.
## Socket       inet:8891@localhost
Socket inet:8891@127.0.0.1

##  Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
##  privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
Umask   002

##  This specifies a text file in which to store DKIM transaction statistics.

##   On-PolicyError
##   SendADSPReports
##   UnprotectedPolicy

## CONFIGURATION OPTIONS

##  Specifies the path to the process ID file.
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

##  Selects operating modes. Valid modes are s (sign) and v (verify). Default is v.
##  Must be changed to s (sign only) or sv (sign and verify) in order to sign outgoing
##  messages.
Mode    sv

##  Log activity to the system log.
Syslog  yes

##  Log additional entries indicating successful signing or verification of messages.
SyslogSuccess   yes

##  If logging is enabled, include detailed logging about why or why not a message was
##  signed or verified. This causes an increase in the amount of log data generated
##  for each message, so set this to No (or comment it out) if it gets too noisy.
LogWhy  yes

##  Attempt to become the specified user before starting operations.
UserID  opendkim:opendkim

##  Create a socket through which your MTA can communicate.
## Socket       inet:8891@localhost
Socket inet:8891@127.0.0.1

##  Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
##  privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
Umask   002

##  This specifies a text file in which to store DKIM transaction statistics.
##  OpenDKIM must be manually compiled with --enable-stats to enable this feature.
# Statistics    /var/spool/opendkim/stats.dat

##  Specifies whether or not the filter should generate report mail back
##  to senders when verification fails and an address for such a purpose
##  is provided. See opendkim.conf(5) for details.
SendReports     yes

##  Specifies the sending address to be used on From: headers of outgoing
##  failure reports.  By default, the e-mail address of the user executing
##  the filter is used (executing_user@hostname).
# ReportAddress "Example.com Postmaster" <postmaster@example.com>

##  Add a DKIM-Filter header field to messages passing through this filter
##  to identify messages it has processed.
SoftwareHeader  yes

## SIGNING OPTIONS

##  Selects the canonicalization method(s) to be used when signing messages.
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

##  Domain(s) whose mail should be signed by this filter. Mail from other domains will
##  be verified rather than being signed. Uncomment and use your domain name.
##  This parameter is not required if a SigningTable is in use.

##  Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
##  privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
Umask   002

##  This specifies a text file in which to store DKIM transaction statistics.
##  OpenDKIM must be manually compiled with --enable-stats to enable this feature.
# Statistics    /var/spool/opendkim/stats.dat

##  Specifies whether or not the filter should generate report mail back
##  to senders when verification fails and an address for such a purpose
##  is provided. See opendkim.conf(5) for details.
SendReports     yes

##  Specifies the sending address to be used on From: headers of outgoing
##  failure reports.  By default, the e-mail address of the user executing
##  the filter is used (executing_user@hostname).
# ReportAddress "Example.com Postmaster" <postmaster@example.com>

##  Add a DKIM-Filter header field to messages passing through this filter
##  to identify messages it has processed.
SoftwareHeader  yes

## SIGNING OPTIONS

##  Selects the canonicalization method(s) to be used when signing messages.
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

##  Domain(s) whose mail should be signed by this filter. Mail from other domains will
##  be verified rather than being signed. Uncomment and use your domain name.
##  This parameter is not required if a SigningTable is in use.

##  Defines the name of the selector to be used when signing messages.
Selector        default

##  Specifies the minimum number of key bits for acceptable keys and signatures.
MinimumKeyBits  1024

##  Gives the location of a private key to be used for signing ALL messages. This
##  directive is ignored if KeyTable is enabled.

##  Gives the location of a file mapping key names to signing keys. In simple terms,
##  this tells OpenDKIM where to find your keys. If present, overrides any KeyFile
##  directive in the configuration file. Requires SigningTable be enabled.
KeyTable        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable

##  Defines a table used to select one or more signatures to apply to a message based
##  on the address found in the From: header field. In simple terms, this tells
##  OpenDKIM how to use your keys. Requires KeyTable be enabled.
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable

##  Identifies a set of "external" hosts that may send mail through the server as one
##  of the signing domains without credentials as such.
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

##  Identifies a set "internal" hosts whose mail should be signed rather than verified.
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

##  Contains a list of IP addresses, CIDR blocks, hostnames or domain names
##  whose mail should be neither signed nor verified by this filter.  See man
##  page for file format.
# PeerList      X.X.X.X

##  Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
Selector        default

##  Specifies the minimum number of key bits for acceptable keys and signatures.
MinimumKeyBits  1024

##  Gives the location of a private key to be used for signing ALL messages. This
##  directive is ignored if KeyTable is enabled.

##  Gives the location of a file mapping key names to signing keys. In simple terms,
##  this tells OpenDKIM where to find your keys. If present, overrides any KeyFile
##  directive in the configuration file. Requires SigningTable be enabled.
KeyTable        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable

##  Defines a table used to select one or more signatures to apply to a message based
##  on the address found in the From: header field. In simple terms, this tells
##  OpenDKIM how to use your keys. Requires KeyTable be enabled.
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable

##  Identifies a set of "external" hosts that may send mail through the server as one
##  of the signing domains without credentials as such.
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

##  Identifies a set "internal" hosts whose mail should be signed rather than verified.
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

##  Contains a list of IP addresses, CIDR blocks, hostnames or domain names
##  whose mail should be neither signed nor verified by this filter.  See man
##  page for file format.
# PeerList      X.X.X.X

##  Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
##  malicious signatures header fields (From and/or others) between the signer
##  and the verifier.  From is oversigned by default in the Fedora package
##  because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems and thus
##  somewhat security sensitive.
OversignHeaders From

SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
```

This is the OpenDKIM part from the Postfix config file (/etc/postfix/main.cf):

```
## OpenDKIM config :)
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

This is the maillog for a test mail I sent( zgrep test@liv2day.com /var/log/maillog* ):

```
/var/log/maillog:Feb  4 11:28:51 vps2 postfix/smtpd[14598]: 134D5B6BE79: client=vps2.brandsomehosting.nl[::1], sasl_method=DIGEST-MD5, sasl_username=test@liv2day.com
/var/log/maillog:Feb  4 11:28:51 vps2 postfix/qmgr[31089]: 134D5B6BE79: from=<test@liv2day.com>, size=1374, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Comment: Where are your dkim config and dkim log? There are no telepaths here.

Comment: @AlexanderMakarenko, thanks for the reply, I've added the OpenDKIM config, Postfix Config and a bit of the maillog. Do you need other files, if so where to find them?

Comment: Don't know how to fix it, but after trying forever I just uninstalled opendkim altogether and re-installed it. That actually worked.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue - couldn't start opendkim, and re-installation might not be an option for all. So adding my solution.

In my case, "TrustedHosts were" missing from "/etc/opendkim/"

```
/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

After creating the file the application started properly.